# String search with any sequence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following two tables:

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_str_match_1
(
    enumber int,
    ename varchar(100),
    eaddress varchar(500)
);

INSERT INTO tbl_str_match_1 VALUES(1,'John Mak','Hno 12 Street Road, USA');
INSERT INTO tbl_str_match_1 VALUES(2,'Shai Lee','UK');
INSERT INTO tbl_str_match_1 VALUES(3,'Smith Watson','Street X01 UAE');
INSERT INTO tbl_str_match_1 VALUES(4,'Ray Gibbs','SA 124');
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_str_match_4
(
    name varchar(100),
    [address] varchar(500)
);

INSERT INTO tbl_str_match_4 VALUES('Mak John','Street Road, Hno 12, USA');
INSERT INTO tbl_str_match_4 VALUES('Shai A Lee','UK');
INSERT INTO tbl_str_match_4 VALUES('A watson Smeeth ','UAE Street X01');
INSERT INTO tbl_str_match_1 VALUES('Henry Jay','RUS OP124');
```

I want to search name from table `tbl_str_match_1` with the passed number and follow the next search with name as input and find the name and address from another table called as `tbl_str_match_4`.

**Note**:

1. Names may be in any sequence like first mid last name or mid last first name or last first mid name, any probability is possible.
2. I want to find the name and address from second table with one extra column i.e percentage match of the string.
3. There will be two search, first on table `tbl_str_match_1` to get name and second on table `tbl_str_match_4` to get name and address.
4. For the first record `John Mak` it should show 100% match with `Mak John`.
5. For the second record `Shai Lee` should show 90% match with `Shai A Lee` because of `A` mid name appearance.
6. Last record that is `Ray Gibbs` will not show in the result set as it has no match with other table values.

--Query:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(   
    SELECT ename FROM tbl_str_match_1 WHERE enumber = 1
)
SELECT name,[address] FROM tbl_str_match_4 WHERE name LIKE '%'+(SELECT ename from CTE1)+'%'
```

**Expected Result**:

Scenario 1: If I pass `enumber = 1` then result should be:

```
    Name        Address                     Matching Percentage
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Mak John    Street Road, Hno 12, USA    100
```

Scenario 2: If I pass `enumber = 2` then result should be:

```
    Name        Address                     Matching Percentage
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Shai A Lee  UK                          90
```

Scenario 3: If I pass `enumber = 3` then result should be:

```
    Name                Address             Matching Percentage
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    A watson Smeeth     UAE Street X01      70
```

Scenario 4: If I pass `enumber = 4` then result should be:

NO RESULT for this, because we don't any relavent match.

```
    Name        Address                     Matching Percentage
    ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: levenshtein distance???

Comment: It's great that you posted sample data properly, but you should also post expected results.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Added expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following helps.

I first tokenize the names in tbl_1 and tbl_4 names by

After that i compare the tokens in tbl_1 with tbl_4

A question on the matching percentage. 
In the example of "Shai A Lee" you have 2 matches("Shai","Lee") out of total of 3("Shai","A","Lee") so shouldnt the matching percentage be 66.67 ?

```
with split_ename_1 
  as (
        SELECT a.enumber
            ,a.ename
            ,a.eaddress      
            ,split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
        FROM  
        (
            SELECT enumber
                ,ename
                ,eaddress
                ,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(rtrim(ename), ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
            FROM  tbl_str_match_1
        ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
     )
,split_ename_4
   as (SELECT a.name            
             ,a.address      
             ,split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
             ,COUNT(*) over(partition by a.name) as  tot_cnt
        FROM  
        (
            SELECT name
                   ,address
                   ,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(rtrim(name), ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
              FROM  tbl_str_match_4
        ) AS A CROSS APPLY data.nodes ('/M') AS split(a)
       )
   select a.ename
         ,count(a.data) as tokens_1
         ,count(b.data) as tokens_4
         ,max(b.tot_cnt) as tot_tokens_4
         ,case when count(b.data)=0 then 0 else count(b.data)*1.00/max(b.tot_cnt)*1.00 end as matching_percentage
     from split_ename_1 a
left join split_ename_4 b
       on a.data=b.data
group by a.ename
```

Comment: Working fine, need a bit performance as its getting 23 seconds for 1 million records, index is there for the searching column.

Comment: At the moment the query does a in-flight split up of the tokens. If the values are static then it might be worth creating a new table and load it with the tokens. eg: create table with the contents of split_ename_1 and split_ename_4 and create indexes on the column-data.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `CTE` in combination with `STRING SPLIT` to do the work

I have added an Identity column in tbl_str_match_4 to make this simpler

```
 DECLARE @enumber INT = 2

;WITH c1 AS 
( 
  --To split the ename from first  table 

   SELECT s.value AS name
   FROM tbl_str_match_1 t
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.ename, ' ') AS s
   WHERE enumber=@enumber
)
,c2 AS
( 
   --To split the matching names from second table of matched records

   SELECT t.id,s.value AS name 
   FROM tbl_str_match_4 t
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.name, ' ') AS s
   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM c1 c WHERE t.name LIKE '%'+c.name+'%')
)
,c3 AS 
( 
   --To calculate the percentage of match

   SELECT id,
   CAST (COUNT(c1.name) AS FLOAT )/ CAST (COUNT(c2.name) AS FLOAT ) * 100 As Percentage
   FROM c2
   LEFT JOIN  c1 on c1.name =c2.name
   GROUP BY id
) 
--display the details
SELECT t.*,c3.Percentage FROM tbl_str_match_4 t
JOIN c3 ON t.Id=c3.Id
```

FOR [**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a3964fedbc448e88a9d904cf0346cbdf)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you.

```
with CTE1 as

(
Select enumber,Ltrim(SubString(ename,1,Isnull(Nullif(CHARINDEX(' ',ename),0),1000))) As Firstename,

Ltrim(SUBSTRING(ename,CharIndex(' ',ename),
CAse When (CHARINDEX(' ',ename,CHARINDEX(' ',ename)+1)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename))<=0 then 0 
else CHARINDEX(' ',ename,CHARINDEX(' ',ename)+1)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename) end )) as Middleename,

Ltrim(SUBSTRING(ename,Isnull(Nullif(CHARINDEX(' ',ename,Charindex(' ',ename)+1),0),CHARINDEX(' ',ename)),
Case when Charindex(' ',ename)=0 then 0 else LEN(ename) end)) as Lastename

From tbl_str_match_1
),

CTE2 as

(
Select *,Ltrim(SubString(name,1,Isnull(Nullif(CHARINDEX(' ',name),0),1000))) As FirstName,

Ltrim(SUBSTRING(name,CharIndex(' ',name),
CAse When (CHARINDEX(' ',name,CHARINDEX(' ',name)+1)-CHARINDEX(' ',name))<=0 then 0 
else CHARINDEX(' ',name,CHARINDEX(' ',name)+1)-CHARINDEX(' ',name) end )) as MiddleName,

Ltrim(SUBSTRING(name,Isnull(Nullif(CHARINDEX(' ',name,Charindex(' ',name)+1),0),CHARINDEX(' ',name)),
Case when Charindex(' ',name)=0 then 0 else LEN(name) end)) as LastName

From tbl_str_match_4
)

select CTE2.name,CTE2.address from CTE1 inner join CTE2 on  CTE1.Firstename = CTE2.FirstName and CTE1.Lastename = CTE2.LastName
where CTE1.enumber = 1
```

Comment: Unable to get the result of first record `enumber = 1`, please check the expected result added.

Comment: do you mean first name,middle name,last name won't come in order?

Comment: Yes exactly. And there is chance of name spell mistake like one table have `Santhana` and another `Santana`, I want to show those records too by showing string percentage match as shown in the expected result for the record 3rd.